# jquery.scrollTo — Scroll on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I'm using the following jQuery plugin on various parts of my site — https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

I can get it to work fine with links, so that when they are clicked it scrolls to a certain part of the page like so:

```
$('#button-top').bind('click', function(e) {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        target = this.hash;
        $('html, body').scrollTo(target, 150);
    } catch (error) {
        alert('error - ' + error);
    }
});
```

But on one page I need it so that it scrolls when the page is loaded, something like:

```
if ($('.gform_validation_error').length > 0) {
    // scroll here
}
```

How would I go about adapting my script so that it scrolls on a page load rather than when clicking a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this** - Use [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function for fire on Page Load

[Here is Working Demo - **Click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/4nm8aud6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($('.gform_validation_error').length > 0) {
       var controlID ="#" + "divToScroll"; // this is ID of DIV where you want to scroll on page load.
        $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(controlID).offset().top
}, 2000);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#target')[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```

Here is a fiddle to show how to do it http://jsfiddle.net/qnr9n989/